# Why does oracle optimiser treat join by JOIN and WHERE differently?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query on which I used query optimiser:

```
  SELECT res.studentid, 
       res.examid, 
       r.percentcorrect, 
       MAX(attempt) AS attempt 
  FROM tbl res 
  JOIN (SELECT studentid, 
             examid, 
             MAX(percentcorrect) AS percentcorrect 
        FROM tbl
        GROUP BY studentid, examid) r 
  ON r.studentid = res.studentid 
     AND r.examid = res.examid 
     AND r.percentcorrect = res.percentcorrect 
 GROUP BY res.studentid, res.examid, r.percentcorrect 
 ORDER BY res.examid
```

What surprised me was that the optimiser returned the following as over 40% faster:

```
SELECT /*+ NO_CPU_COSTING */ res.studentid, 
       res.examid, 
       r.percentcorrect, 
       MAX(attempt) AS attempt 
  FROM tbl res, 
       (SELECT studentid, 
               examid, 
               MAX(percentcorrect) AS percentcorrect 
         FROM tbl 
         GROUP BY studentid, examid) r 
 WHERE r.studentid = res.studentid 
   AND r.examid = res.examid 
   AND r.percentcorrect = res.percentcorrect 
 GROUP BY res.studentid, res.examid, r.percentcorrect 
 ORDER BY res.examid
```

Here are the execution plans for both:

[image: Execution plans]

How is that possible? I always thought the optimiser treats JOIN exactly as the WHERE clause in the optimised query...

Comment: Your second statement has an optimizer hint `NO_CPU_COSTING` that the first doesn't have.  It is not surprising that the two are optimized differently.

Comment: Could you explain that to me in more details? What does no_cpu_costing do?

Comment: . . You can Google that and look it up in the Oracle documentation.  The important point is that optimizer hints affect optimization of the query, which is the root of your question.  You need to look at the plans of both using the same hints.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the execution plans (looks like you started to but they're not there). Thanks.

Comment: NO_CPU_COSTING was a hint in 10g that instructed the optimizer to ignore CPU costs and optimize purely on the basis of I/O costs.  It's not mentioned in the 11.1 version of the tuning guide, leading me to believe it was not very useful and was quietly dropped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [here](http://www.oaktable.net/content/nocpucosting):

> In general you should find that the cost of a table scan will increase
>   when you enable CPU Costing (also known as "System Statistics"). This
>   means that your improved run time is likely to be due to changes in
>   execution path that have started to favour execution plans.  There are
>   a few articles about system statistics on my blog that might give you
>   more background, and a couple of links from there to other relevant
>   articles:
>   http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/category/oracle/statistics/system-stats/

In other words, your statistics might be stale, but since you have "turned them off" for this query, you avoid using an inefficient path: hence the (temporary?) improvement.